# How do I access the overridden child component's template in an Angular 2 unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, angular

So if I have this

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ComponentToTest, ChildComponent, MockChildComponent],

        });

 TestBed
        .overrideDirective(ChildComponent, MockChildComponent);
```

What are some ways I have to access the child/mock child component's template in the test?

Comment: The template should be rendered in the parent template. So just access it from the parent nativeElement. Other than that, please provide a better example and explain what exactly you need to access

Answer (score 2):

The best way to override child components is simply to do,

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ParentComponentToTest, MockChildComponent],

    });
```

Declare MockChildComponent where ChildComponent would be. Only requirement is they should have the same selector in the template.

There is no need to declare the real ChildComponent along with the MockChildComponent, or to use TestBed.overrideDirective.

So this is how you access the MockChildComponent's template, or just the ChildComponent's template.

```
  let fixture: any = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponentToTest); // calls  ngOnInit
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const MockChildCmpDOMEl: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(MockChildCmp)); 

expect(MockChildCmpDOMEl[0].nativeElement.textContent).toBe("whatever is rendered by the first MockChildComponent").
```

Comment: so if the childMockcomponent had a method I wanted to spy on. How would I get a reference to the childMockcomponent, so I could add the spy?